# Storing Hashed Passwords in PHP Code,Is it secure?

Tags: php, security, authentication

I need a page that is only shown to authorized uses.so i plan to use sessions.
There will only be a single user and the password wont change.So i plan to do something like this

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['password']) )
{
    if($_POST['password']=="myhashedpassword" )
    {
        // auth okay, setup session
        $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['username'];

        // redirect to required page
        header( "Location: index.php" );
     } else {
        // didn't auth go back to loginform
        header( "Location: loginform.html" );
     }
 } else {
     // username and password not given so go back to login
     header( "Location: loginform.html" );
 }

?>
```

I was wondering about the security of this approach.I dont need total security.. hope its fair.

Comment: If you hover over the security tag, you will see the following text: "If your question is not about a specific programming problem, please consider instead asking it at Security.SE: http://security.stackexchange.com"

Comment: No definitley it is NOT secure!

Comment: @bub what is not? why?

Comment: First off all you need to optimize your code.

Comment: @Ivar its related to a specific programming problem.what else you think it is?

Comment: if you're only going to have the one user, why not just use `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd`? that's pretty secure in its own right.

Comment: Well, your quesiton is whether it is secure or not to store (hashed) passwords in your code. I don't see any problem with the code itself. On Security SE there are a ton of people who probably have a better view on it then here on SO.

Comment: A potential maintenance nightmare; every time you need to change the password, you need to change your code.... and insecure: if the code is in a source control repository, then everyone with access to source control also has that password

Comment: @MarkBaker I agree the OP's approach isn't exactly *best practice*, but you're claiming that it's insecure because the OP might decide to publish the password. That would just be *daft*, wouldn't it? I think we can assume that's not going to happen. Also, why is this a maintenance nightmare? There is only one user, and only one password. It has to be changed *somewhere*...

Comment: @squeamishossifrage - If there is only one developer, then it's less of an issue; but still it requires a code change every time you want/need to change the password, and that's extra work, especially if you're using a source control system, because you then have the extra push/commit/publish steps

Comment: @squeamishossifrage - And if there are several developers, but you don't want to share the password/hash among them all, then you can't easily control it because it is included in the code

Comment: @squeamishossifrage - nor can you have separate passwords for development/testing/uat/staging/production environments

Comment: @MarkBaker Well, yes. If these problems existed, then they would be problems.

Comment: I simply raise potential issues - I know all too well how one user can become multiple users over time, and how a change of user shouldn't retain the same password for the new authorised user, or how easy it is to accidentally publish your passwords publicly in a vcs like github.... if the OP simply wanted an affirmation that their approach was secure enough, then they shouldn't have bothered asking the question

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Im the only person who will be using this and it wont be publicly available.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks... but how can i use it?

Comment: @techno I would go with nerdylist's answer. Scott Arciszewski makes some valid points, but you can avoid them all if you use php's [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function as the "hash_algo". Apache's website explains how to use [.htaccess and .htpasswd](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/htpasswd.html) to restrict access to a folder. Make sure you use the `-B` option to select bcrypt instead of MD5 hashing. [This page explains why bcrypt is better than MD5.](https://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/)

Comment: @techno You're welcome. David Walsh has a pretty good article on doing this https://davidwalsh.name/password-protect-directory-using-htaccess - Then look for *"To generate encrypted passwords for your .htpasswd file, you can use my .htaccess password generator."* on that same page. You can further your research using these keywords *"protect a folder with htaccess htpasswd php"*. That's what I would use for a single user, if there will always be one user. And I understood what you meant by *"myhashedpassword"* ;-) as it was an example which I got. *Cheers*

Comment: @techno *Addendum to the above*: Use a system path outside the public area, as shown in David's article.

Comment: @techno Oops. That article I left you, says he uses MD5. I thought it used `crypt()`. Here's one https://www.addedbytes.com/blog/code/password-protect-a-directory-with-htaccess/ which includes an .htpasswd generator and another http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/create-password-for-htpasswd-file-using-php/ - *Good luck*.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks a lot for the advice Fred :)  Will see the articles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three reasons why I would say not to do this:

1. You're comparing a plaintext password (`$_POST['password']`) with a constant string. Even if the constant string is hashed, your password isn't, so you're effectively treating the hash as a password now. [Pass the hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pass_the_hash).
2. [Timing attacks](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2014/11/its-all-about-time.html).
3. [Using `==` to compare hashes in PHP](https://www.whitehatsec.com/blog/magic-hashes/) leads to unpredictable results.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Im the only person who will be using this.I need to use this is to add some values to the database easily without the need for doing it manually via `phpmyadmin`.This page wont be publicity available.I will replace the `==` with `strcmp`.Do you have any suggestion for this?

Comment: `password_verify($yourPassword, $aBcryptSaltedHashOfYourPassword)`.

Answer (score 3):

Overall I think this would be frowned upon but it is not completely insecure because they are not seeing the plaintext password. It removes the need for someone to get access to say the database to get the hash and then trying to bruteforce it. So a bit easier.

Also, this will not work if($_POST['password']=="myhashedpassword" ) because you are comparing the hashed password to a plaintext password from the post. So you would really need to do

```
if( hash_algo($_POST['password']) == "myhashedpassword" ){//stuff}
```

My suggestion would be to do this as a normal authentication or add a flag to user accounts that have access to the page and check on that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.This is not working code, just a demonstration.I'm the only person who will log in to this page, to add entries to a db.hope this approach is secure enough.

Comment: "But it is not completely insecure" Timing attacks. :|

Comment: @ScottArciszewski "not completely insecure because they are not seeing the plaintext password" is the whole point of that statement. Yes given this setup is not safe hence the brutefore and yes other attacks as well. However, a Timing attack is more against the hash algorithm rather then his code implementation I believe.

Comment: See my answer for a more in-depth explanation. ;P

Comment: @ScottArciszewski the artilce was a great read and I now have a much better understanding of Timing attacks.

Answer (score 2):

Never hardcode passwords. Some of the reasons are:

- It is harder to keep source code secret than it is a key.
- Any vulnerabilities in your site that allow reading of source code may reveal the password.
- Passwords from development will end up in production.
- It is impossible to change passwords without redeploying (you say it won't change, however what do you do in case of breach?).

Comment: I wont store plain text password.I will compute the hash and store it.

Comment: The thing is ...if the site is breached ... everything is breached ..so im not talking about that level of security :)